# If the VP resigns, can the 25th Amendment still be invoked?

Tags: united-states, president, cabinet, vice-president, twenty-fifth-amendment

There is current news of [several of Trump's cabinet members resigning](https://www.nytimes.com/article/trump-resignations.html) with Trump only having 13 days left in his presidency.

**Question:** If [Mike Pence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Pence) were to resign his vice presidency, with such a small amount of time left in Trump's presidency, what significance would that have on the probability of the invocation of the [25th Amendment](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/amendment/amendment-xxv)?

### Why, context, sub-questions, or whatever you want to call it...

- Since [Pelosi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Pelosi) and [Schumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Schumer) are threatening another impeachment and even [called Pence but put on hold for 25 minutes](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9123033/Republican-congressman-Adam-Kinzinger-demands-Mike-Pence-remove-Donald-Trump-25th-Amendment.html) and told Pence would not come to the phone, it makes me wonder what this would mean if Pence steps down next.
- Would that mean [Pelosi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Pelosi) becomes vice president or does that mean Trump get's to pick anyone else to fill in that spot which he chooses or does that spot stay vacant for the remainder of the term.
- Would there even be enough time to go through the normal process to properly fill this position per protocol.
- Would this mean less leverage for Trump to dissuade his own picked cabinet members from invoking it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As a practical matter, if Pence were to resign, the already slim probability of invoking the 25th amendment would decrease to almost zero.

If Pence resigned, the Vice Presidency would be vacant and it would be up to the President to nominate and both houses of Congress to confirm a new Vice President. Theoretically, this could be done quite quickly if the President, the Senate majority leader, and the Speaker of the House wanted to fill the vacancy. But if that happened today, it is unlikely that either side would be particularly eager to get a replacement in office for the final 2 weeks of Trump's term. Trump would be under no obligation to immediately nominate a replacement while Schumer and Pelosi would have no obligation to rush a confirmation process.

If the Vice Presidency is vacant, invoking the 25th amendment gets much more complicated. The 25th amendment requires the Vice President and a majority of the cabinet to declare that the President is unable to discharge the duties of the office. One could argue that if the Vice Presidency is vacant, it would fall to the next in line under the Presidential Succession Act (Speaker Pelosi) to make such a declaration. But that is not obviously correct - nothing in the Presidential Succession Act explicitly covers vice presidential succession. You could also argue that, in the absence of a VP, the 25th amendment allows a majority of the cabinet to remove the President, but that is also not obviously correct. So attempting to invoke the 25th amendment without a sitting VP would produce a serious Constitutional question. Assuming that Trump chose to argue that whichever theory of invocation of the 25th amendment was invalid (which he almost certainly would), you would have two people making plausible claims that they hold the office of President which would generally be a terrible result that would lead to vastly more chaos until the inauguration.

If you make the "Speaker of the House as acting VP" argument, it would involve the Democratic Speaker of the House trying to remove a Republican President, which would be more politically fraught than if a Republican VP and cabinet attempted to do the same thing. Plus, if Pelosi wanted to argue that the Presidential Succession Act allowed her to act as the VP, she would have to resign her seat in the House (the Constitution prohibits an individual from holding a seat in Congress and holding an executive branch office at the same time). It is unlikely that she would be willing to give up being Speaker (at least until California holds its next election to re-elect her to her vacant seat, and the House holds a new election for Speaker) in order to be a disputed caretaker President for a few days.

Given that there are less than 2 weeks until Biden is inaugurated, it is highly unlikely that anyone would want to open a can of worms by doing a "creative" invocation of the 25th amendment that would inevitably require Supreme Court intervention. If the sitting VP and a majority of the non-acting members of the cabinet (scholars disagree about whether acting cabinet secretaries count for purposes of removing a President under the 25th amendment) were to agree to remove Trump, that would be politically plausible (though unlikely). Anything less than that at this point in time would be decidedly less plausible.

Comment: Also, if any of the cabinet members start talking 25th amendment, it's likely that Trump will simply fire them before they have a chance to vote on it - a bit of a design flaw in the system...

Comment: It's amazing how many bugs in the Constitution have been uncovered during the Trump presidency. Once he's out of office, maybe we should hire him to lead the democracy QA department.

Comment: Right, it's like they thought being ethical is good enough to not worry about flaws or bugs. It's like the [Jim Mora Playoffs, you wanna talk Playoffs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2R2sH2ScBM)... Rather POTUS... "*Ethics, you wanna talk ethics, are you kidding me!*"

Comment: @Barmar :) Indeed, it's complex to anticipate all cases... At least (computer) program tests can be automated. The Constitution is only tested when a Trump-like president  emerges from the crowd...

Comment: *"attempting to invoke the 25th amendment without a sitting VP would produce a serious constitutional question"* - I don't agree that it would produce any question at all. The 25th amendment is not ambiguous on this point: *"whenever  the  Vice  President  **and**  a  majority  of [the cabinet] transmit [their]  written  declaration [...]".* The word "and" here means that without a VP, the procedure cannot be invoked. In any case, it is the VP who becomes acting president, so without a VP the procedure is entirely meaningless.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That's a misunderstanding. No vote needs to take place to initiate the procedure. Instead, the VP and the majority of the cabinet simply need to transmit a written declaration. The dissenting minority don't have to even be aware that this is happening. As soon as the declaration is made, the president *immediately* loses his powers, so firing anyone at this stage (if that is even possible) would have no effect. Your scenario could only happen if the majority were silly enough to broadcast their intentions ahead of time.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Also bear in mind that this was never the intended use for the 25th amendment. It is meant to be used in cases where the president is "unable  to  discharge  the  powers  and  duties  of  his office". Presumably in such cases the president would also be unable to fire anyone.

Comment: @JBentley, the cabinet would probably at least have to discuss amongst each other to figure out who's on board, though. It would be hard to hide that from the president if there were any defectors. But you are correct that the 25th amendment was intended more to answer the Cold War question "Who gets the nuclear codes if the president is in the hospital?" and less "What if we just figured out the president is insane?"

Comment: @SethR Yes, it's true there is plenty of potential to mess up. But if they were smart it would be done by 1-1 conversations with the VP. If he is in favour he would keep it to himself, and if he's not in favour then it doesn't matter anyway since his participation is required. On the other hand, if Trump wants to be sneaky (and if there was any kind of real risk of 25th being invoked) he could simply pre-emptively fire everyone who isn't unwaveringly loyal to him.

Comment: @JBentley if the minority of cabinet members who aren't participating don't even know that it's happening, can they even be said to be "dissenting"?  Maybe they're just unavailable.  Also, if he fired the whole cabinet he would only increase his chances of being impeached, just as Wednesday's events seem to be working against him and just as pardoning himself would increase the probability of a federal prosecutor charging him with a crime.

Comment: @JBentley: Being disconnected from reality to an extent that would get an ordinary person who incited a riot remanded for psychiatric examination ISN'T being unable to discharge the duties of the office?

Comment: @jamesqf Well, that's highly debatable, but in any case not my point. Even if what you're saying is valid, it isn't the type of scenario for which the 25th was originally intended, and I was addressing the first comment which said "a bit of a design flaw in the system". It's not a design flaw if it's being used for something it wasn't designed to cover.

Comment: @JBentley: Indeed. And the president has the power to challenge it, in which case it goes before the Senate, requiring two-thirds thereof.

Comment: @Joshua, it goes to both houses to decide, and they have 21 days to do it. Being that Trump only has 12 days left in his term, it would be easy enough for the House to just run out the clock, even if the Senate didn't want to go along with it.

Comment: @JBentley: Hardly debatable at all, unfortunately. As far as whether the 25th Amendment was intended to cover the case of an insane President, I think it was, though I have no idea how there could be a definitive answer.  Certainly the idea of an insane President in charge of nuclear launch codes was a matter of public concern at the time the amendment was adopted.

Comment: If the VP is out of action or the post is vacant, could the President _pro tempore_ of the Senate invoke the 25th Amendment?  Or have I found another case where the answer is "No, and please submit a bug report"?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Section 4 of the 25th Amendment cannot be invoked if the Vice President resigns (unless the President nominates, and a majority of both Houses of Congress confirm, a new Vice President). Section 4 of the 25th Amendment says:

> Whenever the Vice President and a majority of either the principal
> officers of the executive departments or of such other body as
> Congress may by law provide, transmit [...]

So by that language, it seems to require:

1. The Vice President, and
2. Either

   a. a majority of the cabinet members, or

   b. a majority of another body that Congress provided by law

No matter if Congress provides another body or not, the Vice President is required. So if the Vice Presidency is vacant, this cannot be satisfied. There is no concept of "Acting Vice President" in the Constitution -- only Acting President.